# Can I control number of TCP Connections per second in curl?

Tags: curl, limit

I am trying to make one traffic generator tool in linux centOS 6.5. I am using curl for this purpose. I can generate traffic from virtual interfaces using curl but I don't know if I can control number of established TCP connections per second here. Can I control number of TCP Connections per second in curl? Is it possible? How?